# How to pipe a string to netcat and then keep connection open?

Tags: netcat

I want to connect to a remote a server using `netcat` (or something similar), send a string which I want to `echo` from command-line, and then want to keep connection open. I tried different variation of piping `echo` or `cat` to `netcat`, but none worked. How can I achieve the same on Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit?

Comment: *".... and then I want to keep the connection open"*. In order to do what? Why?

Answer (score 1):

To keep the netcat listening you could use the option `-k`, from the man:

```
-k      Forces nc to stay listening for another connection after its 
        current connection is completed.  It is an error to use this 
        option without the -l option.
```

You could use something like:

```
nc -lk 8080
```